# Pending suggested edits should be shown on the mobile site

Tags: feature-request, editor, mobile-web

I have many times noticed that the `Edit` button is missing on the mobile page and it seems the reason is because there is a edit pending. (`Edit(1)`)

Can this button be made visible on the mobile page?
I understand that it will mean you get moved to "full" page to make the approve/dismiss/improve just like when you look at the edit history of a question/answer.

Images to show what I'm talking about:

**Mobile page:**
[image]

**Full page:**
[image]

Comment: Agreed. This is annoying and there isn't anything that would indicate to a user why the edit option is mysteriously missing.