# Why couldn't I edit this question on the mobile site?

Tags: support, edits, mobile-web

I came across the following question ([Output keeps saying: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57736280/output-keeps-saying-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password?noredirect=1#comment101911820_57736280)) that was tagged with sqlserver. After verifying the user was actually on my MySQL, my comment prompted them to change the tag to xampp. I was going to add/change to MySQL but there wasn't an edit button despite refreshing several times:

> [image]

I posted another comment suggesting they tag to MySQL  and refreshed another couple of times and the edit option reappeared, but it got me wondering what the reason is for it being hidden? When are questions not editable by users who have edit privs? Is it a time based thing such as "within 5 minutes I the most recent edit by the OP"?

Comment: Probably because there was a pending edit suggestion at that time.

Comment: That suggested edit seems plausible: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57736280/timeline

Answer (score 6):

In the Mobile view the Edit button is removed once there is a pending edit. That is a bit counter intuitive as the full site does have this *edit (1)* indicator instead.

The timeline seem to confirm that an edit was involved: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57736280/timeline

There is an open feature request from a couple of 6 to 8 weeks ago that you might want to support:

[Pending suggested edits should be shown on the mobile site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354569/pending-suggested-edits-should-be-shown-on-the-mobile-site)

Comment: Using the responsive version is also an option. It shows if there's pending edits.